# How to update value in Tkinter plot of brain slices to be able to page through different brain volumes from a 4D image

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to design a python gui to be able to assess impacts of motion by plotting brain slices, the framewise displacement timeseries, and different outputs of motion detection algorithms. I want to be able to slide through each of the brain volumes individually (180 volumes per scan) so that I can compare the FD timecourse to what the actual brain data looks like.

I've been using tkinter and I can plot several slices of one brain volume, but I'm having updating volume that is selected. I've tried creating buttons to advance and go back, and also using a tkinter Scale.

```py
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import os
import nibabel
from nilearn import plotting
from nilearn import image
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons
data_path = os.getcwd()
file='sub-HV01baseline_task-EA1_bold.nii'

file_path = os.path.join(data_path,file)

EA1=nibabel.load(file_path)
struct_arr2 = EA1.get_data()
vol=1

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(10,5), dpi=100)
class App:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.event_num = 1
        frame = tk.Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.txt = tk.Entry(frame,width=10)
        self.txt.pack(side="bottom")
        self.lbl = tk.Label(frame, text="FD Value")
        self.lbl.pack(side="bottom")
        self.btn = tk.Button(frame, text = "Update",command=self.clicked)
        self.btn.pack(side="bottom")
        self.txt.focus()
        self.var =tk.IntVar(frame)
        self.var.set(0)
        self.vol_scale=tk.Scale(frame,from_=0, to=180,orient="horizontal",sliderlength=20,command=self.show_slices(fig))
        self.increase_btn = tk.Button(frame, text = "Increase",command=self.show_slices(fig))
        self.increase_btn.pack(side="bottom")

        self.vol_scale.pack(side="bottom")
        #self.spin = tk.Spinbox(frame, from_=0, to=180, width=5, textvariable=self.var)
        #self.spin.pack(side="bottom")
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,master=master)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP)


    def clicked(self):
        res = "FD = " + self.txt.get()
        self.lbl.configure(text = res)

    def show_slices(self,fig):
        vol = self.vol_scale.get()
        slice_0 = struct_arr2[:, :, 10,vol]
        slice_1 = struct_arr2[:, : , 15,vol]
        slice_2 = struct_arr2[:, :, 20,vol]
        slice_3 = struct_arr2[:, :, 25,vol]
        slice_4 = struct_arr2[:, : , 30,vol]
        slices=[slice_0, slice_1, slice_2, slice_3, slice_4]
        axes = fig.subplots(1, len(slices))
        #svol = Slider(axes, 'Vol', 0, 180, valinit=0, valstep=1)
        fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0, wspace=0)
        for i, slice in enumerate(slices):
            axes[i].xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
            axes[i].yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
            axes[i].imshow(slice.T, origin="lower")
root=tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Currently I'm getting an error that "App has no attribute 'vol_scale'" even though I've defined it above.

Comment: `command=self.show_slices(fig)` calls the function *right now* (that's what those parentheses mean), and uses its return value (which is None) as the command to be executed when the slider is moved.  You want `command=self.show_slices` instead (and get rid of the `fig` parameter to the function so that it can be called this way).

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper. However after making that change I get an error that "show_slices() takes 1 positional argument but two were given"